# Conversion error setting value for h:selectManyListBox

Tags: java, drop-down-menu, seam

I am using seam to try to make a web application and i am trying to make a drop-down box that shows vehicles that are stored in a database and allows the user to select multiple ones. It all works up until it tries to store it in the object.

It gives me the error "sourceId=createEmployee:vehicle[severity=(ERROR 2), summary=(Conversion Error setting value '1 6' for '#{employeePort.vehicle}'.), detail=(Conversion Error setting value '1 6' for '#{employeePort.vehicle}'.)]"

the 1 and the 6 are the vehicle ids and i am trying to store them in a String in my bean.

here is my code for the drop-down:

```
<h:selectManyListBox id="vehicle" value="#{employeePort.vehicle}" required="false">
    <s:selectItems value="#{employeePort.getVehicleIdList()}" var="veh" label="#{veh} #{employeePort.getModel(veh)}"/> 
</h:selectManyListBox>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're selecting multiple items from a list(`value="#{employeePort.getVehicleIdList()}"`) and trying to save them as a string(`value="#{employeePort.vehicle}"`).  Either set them to a list(`value="#{employeePort.vehicleList}"`) or create your own custom converter to convert the list to a string.